# C# Programatically change cell format of all Excel cells to General

Tags: c#, excel, interop

As part of an ETL process I am importing data from a variety of different Excel files into a database. Before this happens I need to be able to change the cell format of all cells in an excel worksheet to be in the "General" format.

I have made a start but I'm afraid I dont know how to progress after this:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
.
.
.
String FilePath = "Code to get file location from database"
String SheetName = "Code to get SheetName from database"

Excel.Application MyApp = new Excel.Application();
MyApp.Visible = false;
Excel.Workbook myWorkbook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath,Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

//Code here to convert all rows to data type of general and then save

MyApp.Workbooks.Close();
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Range.NumberFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx) property:

```
var myWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)myWorkbook.Worksheets[1];
myWorksheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "General";
```

Please note that this may cause problems if your sheet contains date values.